# permission denied in Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and I am trying to run a container following [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-docker-handbook/) tutorial and was running into some issues while using the `--volume` or `-v` as shown below:

```
docker run -v <absolute path to host directory>:<absolute path to container working directory> <image id>
```

So mine looks like this:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /usr/app/node_modules -v "$(pwd)":/usr/app 900a3497fc39
```

The error thrown is this:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /usr/app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/app/package.json'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/app/package.json'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/app/package.json'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-12T13_39_38_626Z-debug.log
```

I have built the image without any issues:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.55kB
Step 1/6 : FROM node
 ---> f1974cfde44f
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /usr/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 120da5dd5fa4
Step 3/6 : COPY ./package.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 040ba41014c8
Step 4/6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 96315e12e5d0
Step 5/6 : COPY . .
 ---> db93b8725037
Step 6/6 : CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
 ---> Running in 9c9d58318420
Removing intermediate container 9c9d58318420
 ---> 900a3497fc39
Successfully built 900a3497fc39
```

My `Dockerfile.dev` looks like this:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

And the package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "vite-counter",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.0-beta.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-beta.15"
  }
}
```

From what I understand, I do not have sufficient permissions in the container to run this. This is exactly what I was following in the tutorial. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Use `COPY` on behalf of `node` user (look at answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66818650/10438425, https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1262#issuecomment-677577653)

`COPY --chown=node:node package.json .`
`RUN npm install`
`COPY --chown=node:node . .`

Comment: Or just take look at answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66818650/10438425